# How to submit non-bound h:inputTextarea without refreshing the page with JSF?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

I have a `h:form` with a text token. This text token has none, some or all translations for the languages which are supported (e.g. en, fr, de, es).

The translation relation described in the `Text` entity looks like this.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="textUnit", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Collection<Translation> translation;
```

I bind the text token to the backing bean like this.

```
<h:inputHidden id="textId" value="#{textController.id}" />
```

Within the same form I loop thru the supported translations for my website (Every translation is return by this query. If there is none for a language, then one empty `Translation` entity is create and is empty).

```
<ui:repeat var="trans" varStatus="status"
                            value="#{translationController.getAllTranslationsByTextId(textController.id)}">
```

This all works great.

Here is my question (same as in the title). How to submit non-bound h:inputTextarea without refreshing the page with JSF?

```
<h:inputTextarea id="translation" value="#{trans.translation}" cols="50">
   <f:ajax listener="#{translationController.translationChanged}" event="change" execute="@form" />
</h:inputTextarea>
```

I don't know how I could send these looped (`ui:repeat`) `h:inputTextarea`s to my `textController` on `change` of a value and then use

```
public void translationChanged(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                .getRequest();
    // do something
}
```

to retrieve the submitted variables - BUT WITHOUT REFRESING THE PAGE. Does anyone have a hint?

I don't care if all translations are submitted or just the one I changed. It's just important that I know the relation to the `Text` instance (entity).

I noticed that a request is sent to the server everytime I leave an `inputTextarea`. But it does not hook into the translationChanged method. Here the Log of the JSF phases that this request run thru.

```
19:39:51,391 INFO  [org.exadel.helper] (default task-40) L:54 BEFORE RESTORE_VIEW 1
19:39:51,455 INFO  [org.exadel.helper] (default task-40) L:67 AFTER RESTORE_VIEW 1
19:39:51,455 INFO  [org.exadel.helper] (default task-40) L:54 BEFORE APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2
19:39:51,471 INFO  [org.exadel.helper] (default task-40) L:67 AFTER APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2
19:39:51,471 INFO  [org.exadel.helper] (default task-40) L:54 BEFORE PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3
19:39:51,471 INFO  [org.exadel.helper] (default task-40) L:67 AFTER PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3
19:39:51,471 INFO  [org.exadel.helper] (default task-40) L:54 BEFORE UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4
19:39:51,471 INFO  [org.exadel.helper] (default task-40) L:67 AFTER UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4
19:39:51,471 INFO  [org.exadel.helper] (default task-40) L:54 BEFORE INVOKE_APPLICATION 5
19:39:51,471 INFO  [org.exadel.helper] (default task-40) L:67 AFTER INVOKE_APPLICATION 5
19:39:51,471 INFO  [org.exadel.helper] (default task-40) L:54 BEFORE RENDER_RESPONSE 6
19:39:51,487 INFO  [org.exadel.helper] (default task-40) L:67 AFTER RENDER_RESPONSE 6
19:39:51,487 WARN  [com.doe.webapp.controller.general.filters.UriLoggingFilter] (default task-40) L:69 Multiple URI access to the same resource of the same user: /ccms/admin/text.jsf
```

Comment: Your question is not clear: do you want access to the `translation` view component in your backing bean, from within `translationChanged`?

Comment: @kolossus Yes. I want access to all fields which are within the form tag (I think that makes it the translation view component, doesn't it?). Why? Because I need the token id (text id), the locale (e.g. en-UK) and the translation text in order to save `onchange` to the database. Without these 3 data pieces it makes no sense to save anything. I'm saying, I don't mind if the other translation rows (locale and translation text) are submitted. In this case I simply would save all translations. My concept of displaying the data and saving it might be wrong. Feel free to propose another approach.

Comment: @kolossus I think my approach is a bit weak, because I have no representation of the translations in any backing bean (the `text` token might simply not have a translation for every language!!!). I'm thinking it is smarter to simply collect the data for atranslation with javascript and then send an AJAX request on change to a REST resource. Are there other options with JSF2?